# Vuetify v-snackbar color attribute is not working

Tags: vuetify.js, vuejs3

Hello I have a question regarding the color attr in the snackbar when I try to set the custom color
and apply the snackbar my entire page turns into blank color (same as the color I choose) except the snackbar itself
any suggestion as to why this accrues?
https://prnt.sc/_xwKs2cOO3g6
but if you type
color="success" it is working fine
writing color="#colorcode" makes this error

Comment: Remember that Vuetify for Vue 3 is still in beta and not all features or functionality from Vuetify 2 are included, and some things not working is to be expected.  Since the Vuetify 3 API docs don't mention how to use the color prop I would assume that they haven't yet developed it to the point where you can use hex color codes unfortunately.

Comment: It was a bug: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/commit/009fdd8f4c9ce5caf46a27668ffeecdbc82f684d